# How do I append an entire column to the end of another column in r?

Tags: r

I have col3 and col4, both have 5000 rows. I want to make a new column that has 10,000 rows, the first 5000 being col3 and the second 5000 being col4. Or if it's easier they do not actually need to be in order.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: > test$col5 <- dplyr::bind_rows(test$col3, test$col4)
Error: Argument 1 must have names.

Answer (score 0):

are these vestors? A reproducible example would be nice, but some variation of this should work

`new_col <- rbind(col3,col4)`

Comment: I get error replacement has 2 rows, data has 5144

Answer (score 0):

Let's first create a sample dataset (as you haven't given)

```
set.seed(50)
df <- data.frame(col3 = runif(500),
                 col4 = runif(500))

> head(df)
        col3      col4
1 0.70872710 0.1396443
2 0.43765986 0.6179266
3 0.20000490 0.8179890
4 0.76706599 0.2320035
5 0.51316189 0.9072317
6 0.04470388 0.2108911
```

Nor proceed to append like this (**Note you have to create this is as new data frame as previous one has lesser rows than required**)

```
df_new <- data.frame(new_col = c(df$col3, df$col4))

> (tibble(df_new))
# A tibble: 1,000 x 1
   new_col
     <dbl>
 1  0.709 
 2  0.438 
 3  0.200 
 4  0.767 
 5  0.513 
 6  0.0447
 7  0.700 
 8  0.646 
 9  0.0420
10  0.108 
# ... with 990 more rows
```

In case, you have other columns in data which you have to preserve along with this append, then proceed as follows

```
set.seed(50)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:500,
                 col3 = runif(500),
                 col4 = runif(500))

(tibble(df))
# A tibble: 500 x 3
      id  col3   col4
   <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1 0.540 0.0111
 2     2 0.522 0.509 
 3     3 0.371 0.803 
 4     4 0.526 0.274 
 5     5 0.342 0.922 
 6     6 0.450 0.512 
 7     7 0.383 0.698 
 8     8 0.651 0.0556
 9     9 0.491 0.748 
10    10 0.677 0.728 
# ... with 490 more rows

#Process of append
library(dplyr)

df %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(col3, col4)) %>% select(-name)

# A tibble: 1,000 x 2
      id  value
   <int>  <dbl>
 1     1 0.540 
 2     1 0.0111
 3     2 0.522 
 4     2 0.509 
 5     3 0.371 
 6     3 0.803 
 7     4 0.526 
 8     4 0.274 
 9     5 0.342 
10     5 0.922 
# ... with 990 more rows
```

Comment: > test6$col5 <- rbind(test6$col3, test6$col4)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, col5, value = c(2.5, NA, -1.5, NA,  : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 5144